# TFS automatically checks out project file when build, but makes no modifications in it

Tags: .net, visual-studio, tfs

Past:
I modified the name of one project file. (Updated accordingly: source control, references, namespaces, assembly name as well)

Problem:
TFS automatically checks out this one project file (the solution contains 20) when I build the solution. Once without any modifications in it, once with modified ProjectGuid and some times it checks out the vspscc file as well (without modifications in it).

What I tried: I deleted everything in the mapped path on the filesystem and then I Get Latest (the soltuions can always be built), I also revert the checkouts. But the problem persists every time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First please make sure the source control bindings of that project for TFS are correct.

Suggest you to unbind the project and rebind it in TFS. In VS, choose `File > Source Control > Advanced > Change Source Control` Click **unbind** button.

If this is still not work, since you have mentioned the *ProjectGuid* has been modified. Also use a text editor to update all references to `.xxproj` ProjectGUID in all the .sln files you have. So they match the right value stored in the xxproj itself.